# How to return a value outside of a loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to return a value outside of a loop.

```
@order.cart.line_items.to_a.sum { |li|
              if li.shop_product.method_1?
                (li.shop_product.print_locations.to_a.sum { |pl| pl.vendor_price }) + li.shop_product.product.vendor_product.price_method_1
              elsif li.shop_product.method_2?
                (li.shop_product.print_locations.to_a.sum { |pl| pl.vendor_price }) + li.shop_product.product.vendor_product.price_method_2
              end
            }
```

this gets me the value I would like to have.

In my mind something like:

```
@order.cart.line_items.to_a.sum { |li|
              if li.shop_product.method_1?
                method_1_price = (li.shop_product.print_locations.to_a.sum { |pl| pl.vendor_price }) + li.shop_product.product.vendor_product.price_method_1
              elsif li.shop_product.method_2?
               method_2_price =  (li.shop_product.print_locations.to_a.sum { |pl| pl.vendor_price }) + li.shop_product.product.vendor_product.price_method_2
              end
            }
```

and then using:

`price = method_1_price + method_2_price`

..to get the final price.

How can I use the value from the loop, outside of the loop?

I tried that second piece of code but it won't allow me to use the values outside of the loop.  I've been searching on google but not much shows up that has been helpful

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is you can `map` to get a list of prices, and then sum them in a separate step if needed. Altogether it's not that clear what you're trying to do. Can you share what is your goal with these variables?

Comment: Well, the loop gets the sum I want.   I just can't use the result from it outside of the loop.  I want to somehow define the loop and use the value of the loop elsewhere.  Basically, I use this to get a numbers within a method and I need to then call that number in a different spot within the same method

Comment: @maxpleaner yeah you were right.  I wasn't thinking far enough into what you're saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `#map` to transform the collection into the values (getting you the values, outside the loop), then use the resulting collecting and perform `sum`.

Something like this:

```
price = @order.cart.line_items.map do |li|
  if li.shop_product.method_1?
    (li.shop_product.print_locations.to_a.sum { |pl| pl.vendor_price }) + li.shop_product.product.vendor_product.price_method_1
  elsif li.shop_product.method_2?
    (li.shop_product.print_locations.to_a.sum { |pl| pl.vendor_price }) + li.shop_product.product.vendor_product.price_method_2
  end
end.compact.sum
```

`#compact` is used above to filter out `nil`, when the `li` neither matches `method1` nor `method2`.

Comment: I added to my OP  sorry i wasn't clear i realized.  I get the sum I want, I just need to use the value I receive, outside of the loop because I need the number I get to use later in the method.

Comment: Added example of how I want to use it also near bottom

Comment: yes. result from the loop is assigned to `price =` in my answer above, which you can use in Stripe call.